# What's the difference between require and require-dev?

Tags: php, installation, composer-php

I would like to know the difference between `require` and `require-dev`.
The composer website doesn't offer a good explanation the difference between these two.

The part that I don't get is `Lists packages required for developing this package, or running tests, etc.` from [Composer Official Docs.](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

The `require-dev` packages are packages that *aren't necessary* for your project to work and *shouldn't* be included in the **production** version of your project.

Typically, these are packages such as `phpunit/phpunit` that you would only use during development.

Comment: How does composer know the it is in a dev evironment and should use `require-dev`?

Comment: @surfer190 my understanding is that composer doesn't know; you need to execute composer install or update with the --no-dev option in your live environment to avoid installing the dev packages, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Do you even want composer to know?

Comment: @surfer190 By default, "dev" dependencies are installed for the package where you're running `composer install` (what composer terms the "root package"), but not for other packages installed as dependencies.

Comment: I think the real question here is "Will having packages in `require-dev` make Composer complain on `composer update|require`  for packages in `require`?

Answer (score 61):

The key distinction is that Composer will only install `require-dev` dependencies for the "root package" – the directory where you run `composer install`. [The documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#root-package) describes this as:

> The root package is the package defined by the `composer.json` at the
>   root of your project. It is the main `composer.json` that defines your
>   project requirements.

…and the [`require-dev` documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev) specifies that it is "root-only".

In practice, this means that a package's `require-dev` dependencies aren't used if the package is being installed as a dependency for something else (ie it's installed to another project's `vendor` folder).

So if you have `phpunit` in the `require-dev` list for *YourProject*, and I clone down *YourProject* and run `composer install` in the `yourproject/` directory, Composer will install `phpunit` to `yourproject/vendor/`, because it's likely I'm doing some **development** on *YourProject*. As part of doing development I'll probably want to run *YourProject*'s test suite, and to do that I'll need `phpunit`.

But, if I add *YourProject* as a dependency of *MyProject*, installing the `myproject` package will install the `yourproject` package as well, **but it will not install `phpunit`**.

You *can* override this behaviour with the `--dev` and `--no-dev` [options](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install), but the default behaviour is based on whether the package concerned is the *root package*.

Comment: Note that some of the other answers quote sections of the Composer documentation which changed since those answers were posted. The quoted sections are out of date.

Comment: clearest explanation here, after reading this one the others make sense

Comment: Very clear explanation.

Answer (score 56):

seems clear to me:

> require
>
> Lists packages required by this package. The package will not be
>   installed unless those requirements can be met.
>
> ***require-dev (root-only)***
>
> **Lists packages required for developing this package** <sup>(1)</sup>, or running tests,
>   etc. The dev requirements of the root package only will be installed
>   if install is run with `--dev` or if update is run without `--no-dev`.

http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md

---

1. the packages used to develop a package

Comment: It's still not clear which package "this package" is referring to.

Comment: @ScottDavidTesler **this package** the package you provide in your `composer.json` file like `"require-dev": { // this package('s) }`

Comment: @Dagon Who cares how old the thread is? People will still look at it, possibly for many years. Stack overflow is not a normal kind of forum where messages get lost after a few days.

Comment: "The dev requirements of the root package only will be installed if install is run with `--dev`…" This has since been changed in the linked documentation to: "The dev requirements of the root package are installed by default." The above extract is out of date.