# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages for pinterest API

Tags: php, json, composer-php

This is the [Github Page](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP) for API. This is the command I run in composer:

```
composer require dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP 0.2.11
```

and this is the error I get

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package dirkgroenen/pinterest-api-php No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by
>   dirkgroenen/pinterest-api-php[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but
>   these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Here is the link to [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/dirkgroenen/pinterest-api-php) page of the API.

The `composer.json` file has the following data:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "ext-curl": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.7.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.2"
},
```

The requirements in the `composr.json` file match those specified on the packagist page so how can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper format should be:

```
composer require "dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP:0.2.11"
```

Or alternatively, you can add it to your `composer.json`:

```
"dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP" : "0.2.11",
```

Then do a `composer install`

Comment: Do I add it under `require` or `require-dev`?

Comment: That depends on whether or not it is required for your application to run or not. See this post for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29304370/2020002

Comment: I have tried both these methods but I still keep getting the exact same error.

Comment: have you tried just: `composer require dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP` ?

Comment: No, I directly typed `composer require "dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP:0.2.11"`

Comment: Try using just `composer require dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP`

Comment: In my first attempt I had tried `composer require dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP` but that gave me the error so I tried `composer require dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP 0.2.11` and that gave me the same error too.

Comment: Looks like this guys had the same problem: https://github.com/dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP/issues/20 and was able to resolve it by creating a new composer project

Comment: I read that but could not understand what it meant. Should I delete all the files and then try again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121221/discussion-between-you-and-sanjeet-singh).