# Eror with composer install Symphony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I've started to collaborate with one project and to setup it I need to run composer install but it shows me such error. What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suMR8.png)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1 
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony v3.4.25 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.25].
    - don't install symfony/var-dumper v4.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.25 
    - Installation request for symfony/var-dumper v4.2.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/var-dumper[v4.2.6].

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory. You are installing `var-dumper` from sf4 in a sf3 environment.

Comment: @msg how can I change it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages for pinterest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010228/your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set-of-packages-for-pi)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to update your project before use it,
so run `composer update`